# Access child controller of Tabbar view controller from appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am working on deep link redirection in which I have to redirect a user to store detail page directly when clicking on a link.

In a general case, Once the user successfully logged in, the user had a various option as a bottom bar(Using Tabbar controller).

Here my confusion is How I redirect the user to child controller of a tabbar controller from app delegate did finish launching? Currently I create store detail view as a root view and pushed user but my tabbar is not shown so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I think you should use the UITabBarController as your rootViewController and redirect the user by using

`[self setSelectedIndex:indexOfStoreDetailPage];`